# Replacing string of all HREF tags will value from inside HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm having issues trying to insert part of a HREF tag into the string-

```
<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries1/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">Some Text</a>


<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries2/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">Some Text</a>
```

Needs to change to -

```
<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries1/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">familyseries1</a>

<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries2/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">familyseries2</a>
```

So far I have this code which is replacing all of the strings correctly but my each call is only using the first occurence of familyseries, this value is different in all occurrences on the page.

```
$("a.product-name").each(function(){
    var familySeries = $('.product-name').attr('href').split('/')[4];
    $('a.product-name').text(familySeries);
});
```

My current output is-

```
<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries1/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">familyseries1</a>

<a class="link product-name" href="/s/website/website-2/familyseries2/at/abcd.html" itemprop="url">familyseries1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not specifying the correct element in each iteration. The following implementation should fix things:

```
$("a.product-name").each(function(){
    var familySeries = $( this ).attr('href').split('/')[4];
    $( this ).text(familySeries);
});
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/GeneralPoxter/pen/ExXNBMd?editors=1010

Comment: Follow up: the jQuery attr() method only returns the first matched element, and in your original code, you did this over all `product-name` elements (`$('.product-name')`) every iteration.